# What is 'The Thing' the President talks about?

Tags: plot-explanation, white-house-down

I some days ago saw this film [White House Down](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=15ZSU97HKojW8gecjIHwBg#q=white%20house%20down) and the president does "The thing"
twice (during starting and ending of the film). What is "The Thing"?

I actually missed the last scene before which the president says to little girl "wanna see something special?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "thing" was flying the airplane low over the [Reflecting Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Memorial_Reflecting_Pool) at the [Lincoln Memorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Memorial). Obviously, in normal circumstances this wouldn't be allowed, but as he was the President he was able to direct his pilot to do it.

He does this as he considers it fun, but also as it gives him a chance to talk about Lincoln, e.g. The President tells Finnerty that Lincoln was the first president to be in favor of women's voting, which we are then told he mentions every time they fly over the Pool.

Comment: This movie could have been better, from the movie its quite clear that director only wanted action in this movie

Comment: @MukulKumar: Yeah, but that's what the point of it was. A big silly blockbuster :)

Comment: Hehe, still liked the film.